# Powershell ' add-type -Language JScript '

Tags: powershell, jscript

```
Add-Type @'
class Network {
    var WsNetwork,str;
    function getPcName(){
        WsNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network");
        str="PC name: "+WsNetwork.ComputerName;
        return str;
    }
}
'@ -Language JScript

$PcName = [Network]::new()
$PcName.getPcName()
```

How is correct to add this JScript code?
Thats not compiles

UPD--------------------

This works:

```
Add-Type @'
class Network {
    var WsNetwork;
    
    function getPcName(){
        WsNetwork= new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network"); 
        return WsNetwork;
    } 
}
'@ -Language JScript

$PcName = [Network]::new()
$PcName.getPcName().ComputerName
```

But why **return WsNetwork.ComputerName;** not works?

Comment: According to the documentation, JScript [is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7). Anyway, why not use `$env:computername` instead of using WScript for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Jscript.net that's supported, as well as VB.net and F#.net. The 5.1 docs have a examples.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-5.1#example-6--add-a-class-with-jscript-net

Comment: I saw that example, but how correctly write code from question post?

Comment: It's a different language.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET  You can run jscript externally with cscript.  Or access com objects like wscript.network with new-object.

Comment: I don't know that language.  Like someone else said you can easily use `$env:computername`.